# Remove text between tags

Tags: c#, xml, regex, replace

In C# I need to remove a text that could appear between 2 specific close XML tags:

So for example I have this text in a string:

```
</factura>]]></comprobante>
```

And I need to remove this CDATA close elements but this is just an example and could be other text between this 2 close XML tags.

*I need to to this with Regex*.

I tried:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_inputString, @"/(?<=<\/factura>).*?(?=<\/comprobante>)/", "");
```

But didn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your question is about XML, why do you have HTML in the title?  If you're not careful, you're likely to get lots of "don't use regex to parse HTML" responses... which was exactly what I was about to do

Comment: -1 XML is not parsable by RegEx. Have you tried an XML parser instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the delimiter `/` in your regex,

```
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_inputString, @"(?<=<\/factura>).*?(?=<\/comprobante>)", "");
```

And it's better to add `(?s)` DOTALL modifier which matches  the text inside the particular tag even if it contains  newline characters,

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_inputString, @"(?s)(?<=<\/factura>).*?(?=<\/comprobante>)", "");
```

Comment: -1 XML is not parsable by RegEx. Have you tried an XML parser instead?

Comment: @Aron just say the above to the op. It would suits for a small xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I come from PHP so sorry if I fail. I know substitutions and place holders are possible in c# too.

```
pattern = @"(<\/[^>]+>)[^<]+<\/"; 
replace = "$1</";
```

Answer (score -1):

the Syntax for Regex in C# did not need `/`,just remove them:

and `/` donot need to escape either

```
_inputString= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_inputString,
                         @"(?is)(?<=</factura>).*?(?=</comprobante>)", "");
```

Comment: -1 XML is not parsable by RegEx. Have you tried an XML parser instead?

Comment: @Aron What I got is: @Miguel want to do it in `C#`,right?